# how to identity the grid center with saved map center?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created the map using a  gmapping, then save it, but I saw the center of the map doesn't identify with the center of the grid when I run it this command "`roslaunch e100_navigation slam_gmapping.launch"`.
another issue: the coordinates of the map and Odom located outside the map, I found it on the region of the grid. [image: image description]

you see the  localisation of the robot outside the map

I'd like to see it on the map

what is wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336348/how-to-identity--the-grid-center-with-saved-map-center?/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2019-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you already have created a map then you don't have to use `gmapping` anymore. `gmapping` is for SLAM : Simultaneous Localization and **Mapping** so you just need to localize the robot in your map.

What exactly have you run to get this result ? I assume you've just launched `map_server`to get your map and then `gmapping` ? Instead take a look at the file [navigation.launch](https://github.com/gaitech-robotics/RIA-E100/blob/master/e100_navigation/launch/navigation.launch) from your package, they launch the `map_server` node and then they use the package `AMCL` for the localization.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-10-29**:
first of all, thank you @Delb, everything is fine, I just need to create the map in the region of the grid not next to the grid.
I will use it for going to a specific position and use the map coordinate as reference. it is working with me but I want to get a small error as possible. As shown in figure above the coordinates both the map and Odom outside the map.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-31**:\

> I just need to create the map in the region of the grid not next to the grid.

Can you clarify this ? Are you saying that your screenshot shows the map created with `gmapping` or that you want to build another map on top of your previous map ?
You should provide more info about the nodes you've launched to get this result and detail exactly what you want.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-11-05**:
@Delb, thank you so much, it is fine now.

some mistakes before.

**Comment by [Sid05](https://answers.ros.org/users/94909/sid05/) on 2022-05-13**:
Hi,

I face the same issue with the grid not matching the map created.
How exactly did you fix it ?
Please update the specifics before marking it as answer

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2022-05-13**:
did you try to reboot the robot and launch it again?

**Comment by [Sid05](https://answers.ros.org/users/94909/sid05/) on 2022-05-13**:
Yes , I did